# TFS Cube - Unit Test Method Names not showing (showing as "Unknown")

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, analysis, cube, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am new to using the TFS Analysis data cubes and I am trying to get a report of our test results of our automated builds.

We have a CI build running nightly that runs all of our unit tests.  These tests are running fine, we're using the Visual Studio Test Runner as part of the Build Definition and we do indeed see the test results after each build and can drill down in and see the method names and all of the details about the tests.

In attempting to get the TFS data cube to work, I've been unable to figure out how to get the method names to show up at all.

[All Tests Show As Unknown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2O6d5.png)

I get the result above...where every method shows as "Unknown" for it's Title.  Is there some way to get the details I am looking for from the cube?  We're eventually going to have some manual and exploratory testing as part of this process as well, and I've seen examples where the test plans ans suites can be shown there.  And as part of that suite you can apparently map a test into your DLL and pick the method that it corresponds to...

But I feel like I am missing something obvious here, and that all of these unit tests we've written are pretty useless in the "big picture" that the TFS data cube provides if we can't trend them like this over time.  No one wants to go in and look at all of the previous test runs manually (where the method names are clearly visible).  Ideally, I would throw together a quick pivot chart and the method names would be there as clear as day...

Can anyone provide any insight to this, or provide a way to get the unit test method names to show in the cube?

UPDATE:
I have still be unable to find a way to get the method names from my unit tests to show in Excel in any fashion whatsoever.  I did some research on importing unit tests into MTM as test cases, but that seems like it should be entirely unnecessary.  I have the test methods...they are running as part of my tests...they are showing in the database, just not named.  Frustrating.

Here are my pivot chart settings in Excel, thanks for looking.

[Pivot Chart Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd145.png)

Update 2:
Still trying to figure this issue out.  I have rebuilt the data cube and warehouse, seemingly following all of the recommended directions.  Existing tests as well as new tests being run today are still showing as "unknown".

I do notice that there are some warnings in the Application Event log on the server seemingly related to TFS and a warehouse job.  Is this related possibly, or just a distraction?

```
TF53010: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation component or 
extension:

Date (UTC): 3/9/2016 7:56:48 PM
Machine: ServerName
Application Domain: TfsJobAgent.exe
Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=12.0.0.0,     
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v4.0.30319
Service Host: 
Process Details:
  Process Name: TFSJobAgent
  Process Id: 76700
  Thread Id: 101284
  Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Detailed Message: TF30065: An unhandled exception occurred.
Exception Message: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the     
object. (type InvalidOperationException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at     
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationRequestContext.ValidateR    equestContext(Boolean throwOnError)
   at     
      Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationRequestContext.To(TeamFo    undationServiceHost targetHost)
   at     Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationRequestContext.To(TeamFo    undationHostType hostType)
   at     Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.LockResources..ctor(TeamFoundationRequestCont    ext requestContext)
   at     Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseExecutionContext..ctor(TeamFoundatio    nRequestContext requestContext)
   at     Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseSyncJobExtension`1.CheckSchemaLockQu    eue(Object source)
```

Comment: Which report are you reviewing? Or you are customizing your own report?

Comment: Couldn't find a way to get Test Method report. Could you share us how do you generate the report? "Unknow" seems it can't find test method in TFS Analysis cube.

Comment: I am using Excel with a data connection to the TFS Analysis Cube.  I will edit the original question to include an image of my options.  It's very frustrating that the method names don't just transfer over as the 'Title' because this seems to mean that I have to map every one of my unit tests into some sort of 1-1 test scenario somewhere and give it a test name.  That would be very frustrating if that is the case.

Comment: Updated original post with some more info on an issue I am seeing in the event log on the server...possibly related?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to rebuild your warehouse and cube.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Report/admin/rebuild-data-warehouse-and-cube

This may take some time but should resolve the "unknown" issue.

**warning: There may be some data loss if things like builds and test or team projects and collections have been deleted.**

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response.  I took the time to visit the link above and followed all of the directions (including the manual reprocessing of the analysis cube) and all of my tests are still showing as "unknown".

Is there something specific I need to do to the unit tests now in order for their method names to show as the title in the analysis cube at this point?

I don't have a "test plan" associated with these, and no "test case".  These are just unit tests in the code, and they are running during a CI build that we run each night on our dev branch.